# Apagar todos os registros de um banco de dados, exceto um user

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Tenho um banco de dados que preciso apagar todos os registros que existe nela, exceto um usuário que se encontra na tabela **Usuário** com ligação com outra tabela (**AspNetUsers**). Já fiz algumas tentativas pelo *SSMS*, porém sempre esbarro com problemas de referencia e conflitos.

Por exemplo, rodei o seguinte comando:

```
USE [dbTeste]
GO

DELETE FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
  WHERE Id !='52252ba2-8312-4650-b829-c611e2c3cfdb'
  GO
```

> Mensagem 547, Nível 16, Estado 0, Linha 4
>   The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Usuario_dbo.AspNetUsers_ApplicationUser_Id". The conflict occurred in database "matina", table "dbo.Usuario", column 'ApplicationUser_Id'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Preciso só manter esse usuário, que utilizo para o login e apagar todos os registros das outras tabelas.

Comment: Amigo, este erro é referente a outras tabelas que recebem a PK deste usuário, para apagar os usuários, necessitará apagar os registros referentes a PK dos usuários.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [script desta resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/871124/3388148) para gerar as alterações de chave para incluir `ON DELETE CASCADE` que irá excluir automaticamente a linha com a chave estrangeira definida quando a chave primária da tabela que está sendo referenciada for excluída.

```
SELECT DropStmt = 'ALTER TABLE [' + ForeignKeys.ForeignTableSchema + '].[' + ForeignKeys.ForeignTableName + '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + ForeignKeys.ForeignKeyName + ']; ',
       CreateStmt = 'ALTER TABLE [' + ForeignKeys.ForeignTableSchema + '].[' + ForeignKeys.ForeignTableName + '] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [' +  ForeignKeys.ForeignKeyName + '] FOREIGN KEY([' + ForeignKeys.ForeignTableColumn + ']) REFERENCES [' + SCHEMA_NAME(sys.objects.schema_id) + '].[' + sys.objects.name + ']([' + sys.columns.name + ']) ON DELETE CASCADE; '
  FROM sys.objects
 INNER JOIN sys.columns ON sys.columns.object_id = sys.objects.object_id
 INNER JOIN (
   SELECT sys.foreign_keys.name as ForeignKeyName,
          SCHEMA_NAME(sys.objects.schema_id) as ForeignTableSchema,
          sys.objects.name as ForeignTableName,
          sys.columns.name  as ForeignTableColumn,
          sys.foreign_keys.referenced_object_id as referenced_object_id,
          sys.foreign_key_columns.referenced_column_id as referenced_column_id,
     FROM sys.foreign_keys
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns ON sys.foreign_key_columns.constraint_object_id = sys.foreign_keys.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.objects ON sys.objects.object_id = sys.foreign_keys.parent_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns ON sys.columns.object_id = sys.objects.object_id
                          AND sys.columns.column_id = sys.foreign_key_columns.parent_column_id
 ) ForeignKeys ON ForeignKeys.referenced_object_id = sys.objects.object_id
              AND ForeignKeys.referenced_column_id = sys.columns.column_id
 WHERE sys.objects.type = 'U'
   AND sys.objects.name NOT IN ('sysdiagrams')
   AND sys.objects.name = 'AspNetUsers'
```

**Atenção** ao fato de que a `query` acima não suporta chaves compostas.

Após executar os scripts de alteração deverá ser possível executar o `DELETE` da forma que você mencionou.